# Regular expressions in Sublime Text 3 wildcard to uppercase

Tags: json, regex, sublimetext3, wildcard, uppercase

I have these lines of text like:

```
"Suburb_Name": "Hazelwood",
"Suburb_Name": "Hazelwood North",
"Suburb_Name": "Heathcote",
"Suburb_Name": "Sulky",
```

I need to make the various names uppercase, like:

```
"Suburb_Name": "HAZELWOOD",
"Suburb_Name": "HAZELWOOD NORTH",
"Suburb_Name": "HEATHCOTE",
"Suburb_Name": "SULKY",
```

Is there a way of doing this? The file is rather long, 661630 lines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

- in the **search field** use `^("Suburb_Name": ")([^"]*)`
- and in the **replace field** `$1\U$2`

The `\U` is a special replacement modifier that causes the output to be in Uppercase (as per [Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html)).

Comment: @user3121518 Sublime Text 3.1.1 (that's what I've tested it with, usually I use Notepad++)

Comment: find ("Suburb_Name": ")([^"]*)  replace $1\U$2  worked, the little ^ didn't. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
("Suburb_Name": ")([^"]*)
```

Replace

```
$1\U$2
```